# Is there a webextesnion API that makes an http request in the main_frame given a URL and a tabId?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am looking for a way to make an HTTP request for a given URL and tabID. The URL is not provided by the user, but it is taken from within the extension code.

The HTTP request need to be passed to the address bar because I have an `onBeforeRequest` observer that I specified it to "main_frame" URLs must be able to observe that URL (although not entered by the user).

I looked at webNavigation and webRequest APIs with no hope. Is there any way to achieve that?

**EDIT:**
Knowing that I can connect that to a click event. But what is the API that will read the URL, tabId and pass the request to the URL address bar so the `onBeforeRequest` observer can see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
var tabId = 1;
var url = 'google.com';

browser.tabs.update(
  tabId,
  {url: url}
);
```